# Espresso Testing: programmatically select 'never' on smart lock save password

Tags: android, android-espresso, google-signin, google-smartlockpasswords

Doing espresso UI testing on Android and trying to bypass the smart lock screen. Issue is that we are testing in Firebase, and cannot turn off smart lock on the device as a whole since they are in the cloud (I don't believe). The popup is also not a part of the app itself, so I can't get the id using Stetho or Layout inspector. I believe it's another app (or OS feature) drawing on top of our app.

How can I hit the "no thanks" or "never" button in espresso?

[image: Smart Lock]

Comment: You should be able to turn of the Smart Lock functionality on the device under Setttings > Google > Smart Lock for Passwords?

Comment: and wouldn't something like `onView(withText("NO THANKS")).perform(click())` work? or maybe `no thanks` or `No Thanks` or `No thanks` (not sure how it handles caps here)

Comment: @StevenSoneff, I'm testing on firebase, so the phones are in the cloud. I don't know if I can change phone settings programmatically.

Comment: @BartekLipinski the popup screen is in another app. I don't think it exists in the view hierarchy

Comment: Look into UIAutomator (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html).  It works well with Espresso and gives you the ability to manipulate UIs that are outside of your control.

Comment: @StevenSoneff, Jason have you found solution to skip Smart Lock Save credentials dialog in Firebase? Have same issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use uiautomator

**graddle**:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
```

And add it to your **code**:

```
waitSeconds(10) // Waiting for smartlock window
val uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
val currentPackageName = uiDevice.currentPackageName
if (currentPackageName != "your.app.package") {
     uiDevice.pressBack()
}
```